# Retrain tensorflow models(resnet and inceptionV3) from scratch on custom dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I have training images in JPEG format as follows:

/train_dir/class1/img1
/train_dir/class1/img2
...

/train_dir/class2/img1
/train_dir/class2/img2
...

and so on for 10 classes with each class having around 1000 images.

In need to retrain(not fine tune) resnet, inceptionV3 models from scratch on this dataset. How can i do so?
I tried using the methods mentioned here https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#Training but these only seem to work for predefined datasets like imagenet/MNIST/flowers/CIFAR.

---

## Training a model from scratch.

We provide an easy way to train a model from scratch using any TF-Slim dataset.
The following example demonstrates how to train Inception V3 using the default
parameters on the ImageNet dataset.

```shell

```
DATASET_DIR=/tmp/imagenet
TRAIN_DIR=/tmp/train_logs
python train_image_classifier.py \
    --train_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} \
    --dataset_name=imagenet \
    --dataset_split_name=train \
    --dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR} \
    --model_name=inception_v3
```

```

---

I edited the code provided above in hope to train it on my own images as follows -

```
$ DATASET_DIR=/home/harshit/Music/malignant_or_benign/train/
$ TRAIN_DIR=/home/harshit/Music/malignant_or_benign/out/
$ python train_image_classifier.py --train_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} --dataset_name=mal_ben --dataset_split_name=train --dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR} --model_name=inception_v3
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from float to np.floating is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
WARNING:tensorflow:From train_image_classifier.py:398: create_global_step (from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.create_global_step
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_image_classifier.py", line 571, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "train_image_classifier.py", line 404, in main
    FLAGS.dataset_name, FLAGS.dataset_split_name, FLAGS.dataset_dir)
  File "/home/harshit/Downloads/GIT Repos/models/research/slim/datasets/dataset_factory.py", line 52, in get_dataset
    raise ValueError('Name of dataset unknown %s' % name)
ValueError: Name of dataset unknown mal_ben`
```

Comment: Quick warning: resnet has millions of parameters, and you have 10K images in total. Training from scratch is not a good idea unless your test is very very very similar. You are going to overfit the models a lot.

Comment: I do understand your valid point but knowing how it's done is what i am after here not the results.

Comment: Then this is not the place for that. SO is for programming questions, not "please give me code that does X".

Comment: Not asking for code. Asking to point me to the right resource.